# Bind Output of Button Click to a New Span

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

New to Angular2 so I am trying to keep it simple.  I know I should have my feature components separated but right now I just want to make it work.

My goal here is to bind the value of the button click and display that output in a new span and increment the times picked value up by 1.

Edit: I have updated the Component to reflect a working version of showing the name of a randomly generated engineer.  Now it is time to increment.

Template:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>Engineers:</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let engineer of engineers">
    <span>{{ engineer.name }} has been picked: {{ engineer.timesPicked }} times!</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<div>
  <button (click)="getEng($event)">Pick an Engineer</button>
  <span> {{ pickedEngineer }} </span>
</div>
```

Component:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Engineer }  from './engineer'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Engineers';
  engineers = [
    new Engineer("Jim", 0),
    new Engineer("John", 0),
    new Engineer("Bob", 0)
  ];
  myEng = this.timesPicked;
  pickedEngineer = '';

  getEng(){

    var number = Math.random() * 100;

    if (number > 0 &&  number <= 34) {
      var pickedEngineer = "Jim";
    } else if (number > 34 && number <= 66 ){
      var pickedEngineer = "John";
    } else {
      var pickedEngineer = "Bob";
    }
      this.pickedEngineer = pickedEngineer;
      console.log(pickedEngineer);
  }
  }
```

Class:

```
export class Engineer {
constructor(
  public name: string,
  public timesPicked: number) {}
}
```

Comment: Your `getEng()` implementation ignores the parameter that you send in the  click. Also, you have just one button (outside the *ngFor), how come?

Comment: Frankly, I thought passing the $event parameter was good practice but looks a bit unnecessary.

As far as the button outside the ngFor.  I just wanted a roster of engineers and then to be able to randomly call one to be the next person up to answer a question.

Shortly I will be able to add and subtract engineers but that is it the next goal in order to learn forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `pickedEngineer` attribute and bind to the `myEng` property `name`.

```
<span> {{ myEng?.name }} </span>
```

In the `getEng()` method, assign new `myEng` and update the `myEng.timesPicked` value.

EDIT: 
Template change:

```
<div>
   <button (click)="getEng()">Pick an Engineer</button>
   <span> {{ myEng?.name}} </span>
</div>
```

Component change:

getEng(){

```
  var number = Math.random() * 100;

  if (number > 0 &&  number <= 34) {
    this.myEng = this.engineers[0];
    this.myEng.timesPicked++;
  } else if (number > 34 && number <= 66 ){
    this.myEng = this.engineers[1];
    this.myEng.timesPicked++;
  } else {
    this.myEng = this.engineers[2];
    this.myEng.timesPicked++;
  }
}
```

My Edit to be able to give him credit for the answer but also correct a small stack trace error on original component they submitted:

Comment: I just updated the component that actually works in displaying an engineers name.  I still am a little hazy on how you would increment.  Really appreciate you helping out!

Comment: Thank you! There was a stack error on the component code but luckily the error message was crystal clear. client?93b6:80 [default] /Users/USER/Documents/engineer/src/app/app.component.ts‌​:25:17 Cannot find name 'engineers'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.engineers'?

Had to edit the comment to remove my name :)